# CodeIgniter - Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to int

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have a controller which looks like

```
class Products extends CI_Controller    {

    public function __construct(){
        //
        parent::__construct();
    }   

    public function index() {
        //
        $this->load->model('products_model');
        $data = $this->products_model->getProducts();

        $this->load->view('products',$data);    
    }
```

}

And model using Active Record

```
class Products_model extends CI_Model {

    private function getMake()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('make');
        return $this->db->get('manufacturer');
    }

    public function getProducts() {

        $meta_title = "Meta Title";
        $meta_keywords = "keywords";
        $meta_description = "Page description"; 

        $make = array('' => 'Select a make')+$this->getMake();      

        return array("make" => $make, "meta_title" => $meta_title,"meta_keywords" => $meta_keywords,"meta_description" => $meta_description);   

    }
}
```

And a view which is a simple drop down for make:

```
<? echo form_dropdown('make',$make,$this->input->post('make')); ?>
```

Whole combination above throws me an error 'Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to int' on a line

```
$make = array('' => 'Select a make')+$this->getMake();
```

Any clue why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems. First, you are trying to concatenate an object with an array by using a numeric operator, second you're trying to use an object as an array.

You want

```
array_merge(array(''=>'Select a make'), $this->getMake()->result());
```

The actual cause of the error was the `+ $this->getMake()`. You can't simply add an object in PHP, you need to add properties or values of an object. Because PHP doesn't support this, it thought, "AH! a `+`! I know what to do with those! Let's make everything a number!" And so it took the result of `getMake` and then got very angry when it found that it was something which had nothing to do with numbers.

Your second issue is that CodeIgniter does not return an array from `get` it returns a result object. [You can find out more about them here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html), but the long and the short is that you want to call `result` before trying to merge it with an array.

Comment: Now I'm getting this for the drop down:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Try `result_array` instead of `result`

Comment: With result_array I was able to generate a drop down, but each result it goes as separate select option instead of ID as value and MAKE as a choice name

Comment: You'll need to take the result from the DB and format it into the proper `value => choice` array. `form_dropdown()` doesn't do that for you.

Comment: So I need to change whole line array_merge(array(''=>'Select a make'), $this->getMake()->result())?

Comment: @JackTheKnife It seems so.

Comment: OK, I have ended with `$makes_temp = array();
  foreach ($this->getMake()->result_array() as $explode_temp){
    $makes_temp[$explode_temp['id']]=$explode_temp['make'];
  }

  $make = array(''=>'Select a make') + $makes_temp;`